# Is it possible to transfer cookies from a VB.net program to Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: vb.net, cookies, copy, browser, cookiecontainer

I have vb.net 2010 and I need a way to transfer a cookie container from the program I made to web browsers like Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Safari and Mozilla Firefox. All answers are much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I really hope that modern browser have protection against this kind of attacks (yes, you should not be able to write/read cookies from 3 party domain such as *stackoverflow.com*).

If you want to implement user cookie to user browser then let it open some page where there cookie will be implemented to the browser...

Comment: IIRC most browsers still just keep cookies in plain-text files in a specific folder.

Comment: It could be Internet Explorer 6.
Just checked it, Chrome saves it in SQLite 3.x database.